# dart map.entries.firstWhere throws type error

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to get a value using Map.entries.firstWhere method,
but I think I wrote it correctly, but dart throws type error

```dart
final langList = {
  null: "disabled",
  "ko": '한국어',
  "de": 'Deutsch',
  "ru": 'русский',
  "vi": 'Tiếng Việt',
  ...
}.entries.toList();


// in build method
Text(
  langList
      .firstWhere(
        (element) =>
            element.key ==
            translateClientKeyMap[user.clientKey],
        orElse: () =>
            const MapEntry<String?, String>(
                null, "disabled"),
      )
      .value,
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Color(0xff000000),
    fontSize: 10.0,
  ),
)
```

but dart throw `_TypeError (type '() => MapEntry<String?, String>' is not a subtype of type '(() => MapEntry<String, String>)?' of 'orElse')`

I think I chose the right type, but dart throw type error

whats problem?

Comment: I've tried your current code and found no errors.

Comment: Try to replace `final langList` to `List<MapEntry<String?, String>> langList`